# ¿Como incluir Array a consulta SQL en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array, sql

Tengo un Array y una consulta como esta...

```
$existentes = [1,2,3]
$resultado = $link->query("SELECT * FROM mercancia");
```

Todo esto con la finalidad de hacer una consulta la cual de como resultado todos los datos en mercancía excepto los que traiga ese array...

> ¿Como seria esa consulta, teniendo en cuenta que esto sera dinámico? Osea que los datos del Array cambiaran frecuentemente dependiendo el caso.

Comment: Me imagino que quieres comparar los valores del array con alguna columna.  Cual es el nombre de la columna?

Comment: Si cierto olvide eso a medida que resumía la pregunta, pero la columna es la de idmercancia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función implode de php para convertir el arreglo a cadena y en tu where sql utilizar la sentencia not in

Ejemplo:

```
$existentes = [1,2,3]
$resultado = $link->query("SELECT * FROM mercancia WHERE id not in(".implode(",", $existentes).")");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que convertir tu array en una cadena de texto, dependiendo del tipo de columna que sea idmercancia, lo tendrás que hacer poniendo los valores entre comillas (si es de tipo char o varchar) o no (si es un entero o valor numérico).

Luego ese array lo pones en una clausula WHERE con NOT IN

```
"SELECT * FROM mercancia WHERE idmercancia NOT IN ('<CadenaDeTexto>')"
```

En general no es recomendable utilizar * en el SELECT, y es más eficiente enumerar uno a uno y separados por comas, los nombres de las columnas.